# How can I validate a local date time within daylight savings time?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

`Mar 12, 2017 02:39:00 "America/Chicago"` does not exist. When I set the date and time to this value it does not fail. The time gets set to `Mar 12, 2017 03:39:00` an hour later. How can I be notified that this time does not exist. Here is how the time skips forward

```
01:59:59
3:00:00
```

As you can see `02:39:00` will never exist on this date.

Here is the code I am using

```
package com.company;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
        ZonedDateTime dateTimeStart = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 1, 1, 15, 39, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
        ZonedDateTime dateTimeStartUtc = dateTimeStart.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        ZoneId zoneIdDst = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
        ZonedDateTime dateTimeStartDst = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 3, 12, 2, 39, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
        ZonedDateTime dateTimeStartUtcDst = dateTimeStart.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        int y = 90;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your sample doesn't throw an exception because `ZonedDateTime.of(..)` adjusts the date time. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-java.time.ZoneId-) states

> This creates a zoned date-time matching the input local date-time as
>   closely as possible. Time-zone rules, such as daylight savings, mean
>   that not every local date-time is valid for the specified zone, thus
>   the local date-time may be adjusted.

You could use [`ZonedDateTime#ofStrict(LocalDateTime, ZoneOffset, ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofStrict-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneOffset-java.time.ZoneId-) to perform the validation.

> Obtains an instance of ZonedDateTime strictly validating the
>   combination of local date-time, offset and zone ID.
>
> This creates a zoned date-time ensuring that the offset is valid for
>   the local date-time according to the rules of the specified zone. If
>   the offset is invalid, an exception is thrown.

You'll first need to construct a `LocalDateTime`. Then you'll get the `ZoneOffset` for your `ZoneId` for that local date time. Then you can provide all three to `ofStrict`.

For example,

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 3, 12, 2, 39, 0, 0);
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = zoneId.getRules().getOffset(ldt);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofStrict(ldt, zoneOffset, zoneId);
```

would throw

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: LocalDateTime '2017-03-12T02:39' does not exist in zone 'America/Chicago' due to a gap in the local time-line, typically caused by daylight savings
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.ofStrict(ZonedDateTime.java:484)
```

Answer (score 15):

Here a **validation without throwing exceptions.** You only need to ask the zone rules if a `LocalDateTime` is valid within a given timezone:

```
public static boolean isValid(LocalDateTime ldt, ZoneId zoneId) {
    return !zoneId.getRules().getValidOffsets(ldt).isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Note that this method will return `true` also in the case there are multiple valid offsets for the given time. For example, when the clocks are turned back an hour 04:00->03:00, then the time 03:30 will occur twice, with two different offsets. If you want to also detect this case, change the `isValid` method to return `true` only in case the list of offsets has exactly one value: `return zoneId.getRules().getValidOffsets(ldt).size() == 1;`

Comment: @anddero But a `LocalDateTime` in combination with two valid offsets should still be considered as valid meaning it exists in real world (twice at two different instants).

Comment: It may be valid, but it is even more dangerous than having no valid offsets. If the clocks were turned forward 03:00->04:00 then the time 03:30 can have a meaning for someone who forgot to turn the clocks. It just means 04:30. So everyone who inputs a time 03:30 into some web service, it automatically gets translated into the same instant for every user. But if the clocks were turned backwards 04:00->03:00, one user's 03:30 might not be the same as another user's 03:30, so in case of a doctor's appointment, the patient might miss their session by an hour.

Comment: I know you are talking about the *existence* of a time. I am just commenting that if *user input* was validated, both inputs should be considered wrong and the user should be informed. For an ambiguous input, they should explicitly state which one of the valid variants they want to use.