# How to detect an ambiguous DST overlap?

Tags: java, java-8

When daylight saving ends the clock goes back 1 hour. This means there will be 2 `01:30 AM` on Novermber 5, 2017. So here is how it will work

```
01:59:58
01:59:59
01:00:00
01:00:01
```

As you can see when the time approaches 02:00:00 it will go back 1 hour to 01:00:00. This means there will be an overlap of one hour on November 5. I need to detect if the time given is within an overlap period?

Comment: Have you tried parsing these values with the joda time library? I know that I encountered a specific exception from the library when dealing with the dates around the time change so it might give some background on detecting it. I am not sure how the internal java version of joda time handles this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43204894/2491410) in your former SO-post, ask the zone rules and you go:

```
public static boolean isAmbivalent(LocalDateTime ldt, ZoneId zoneId) {
    return zoneId.getRules().getValidOffsets(ldt).size() > 1;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 11, 5, 1, 30);
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
System.out.println(isAmbivalent(ldt, zoneId)); // true, offsets either -5:00 or -6:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the [transition rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getTransitionRules--) then the following may help you:

```
ZoneId yourZoneId = ...
List<ZoneOffsetTransitionRule> transitionRules = yourZoneId.getRules()
                                                           .getTransitionRules();
```

With those you can check whether your given time is within the rule's defined range or when the next transition takes place.

[The ZoneDateTime javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) also contains some hints regarding the "gap" and "overlap" and the corresponding offsets.

If you are only interested in whether your time is a daylight saving's time or not, [`isDaylightSavings(Instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#isDaylightSavings-java.time.Instant-) might help you:

```
ZoneId yourZoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome");
Predicate<ZonedDateTime> isDaylightSavings = 
                           time -> yourZoneId.getRules()
                                             .isDaylightSavings(time.toInstant());

boolean isDaylightSaving = isDaylightSavings.test(ZonedDateTime.of(/* the time to test */, yourZoneId));
// returns true if time is daylight savings time or false otherwise
```

This however may only make sense if your time is already a `ZonedDateTime`.