# Java 8 – Create Instant from LocalDateTime with TimeZone

Tags: java, date, java-8, localdate

I have a date stored in the DB in string format ddMMyyyy and hh:mm and the TimeZone.
I want to create an Instant based on that information, but I don't know how to do it.

something like

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 1, 13, 39);
Instant instant = dateTime.toInstant(TimeZone.getTimeZone("ECT"));
```

Comment: Do you mean `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, TimeZone.getDefault())` ?

Comment: @soorapadman That would return a ZonedDateTime. OP wants an Instant.

Comment: **Never use the 3-4 character abbreviations for time zones.** Those are *not* real time zones, not standardized, and not even unique! Use [true time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format `continent/region` such as [`Europe/London`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London), [`Europe/Paris`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris), `Asia/Kolkata`, `Pacific/Auckland`. If by “ECT” you meant Ecuador Time, use `ZoneId.of( "America/Guayaquil" )`. If you meant central Europe, use an appropriate `Europe/…` zone name.

Comment: This Question is *not* a duplicate of that linked Question. This Question has nothing to do directly with a count of milliseconds.

Comment: “I have a date stored in the DB in string format ddMMyyyy and hh:mm and the TimeZone.” No, you don't, not if you used a date-time data type in defining your DB column such as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (as you should). Date-time columns have no "format" as they are *not* string/text. Retrieve date-time values as date-time objects rather than as Strings. `Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can first create a `ZonedDateTime` with that time zone, and then call `toInstant`:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 15, 13, 39);
Instant instant = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toInstant();
System.out.println(instant); // 2017-06-15T11:39:00Z
```

I also switched to using the full time zone name (per Basil's advice), since it is less ambiguous.

Comment: Almost a perfect Answer, but you should not be encouraging the use of the 3-4 letter pseudo-time-zone codes. Instead use [true time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in `continent/region` format. I'm guessing the author meant *Ecuador Time* for “ECT”. `ZoneId.of( "America/Guayaquil" ) )`

Comment: @BasilBourque "ECT" is actually European Central Time (`Europe/Paris`), so I can see why using the full name would be better ;)

Comment: I have only seen “CET” as central European time. But that's the point, these 3-4 letter codes are a nightmare of ambiguity, and should be avoided like the Plague.

Comment: @BasilBourque why? I just need "UTC" and don't care about a region, it's hard to find an equivalent on the page you linked.

Comment: @Line A date is ambiguous. A few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day, while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec. If you intended the date to be in UTC, use `OffsetDateTime` to determine a moment: `OffsetDateTime.of( LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 ) , LocalTime.MIN , ZoneOffset.UTC )`

Comment: @BasilBourque ok, thanks, but I meant: why not to use short, three-letter form of zone?

Comment: Because 2-4 letter abbreviations (ET, PST, EST, CST, IST, and so on) are not true time zones, not standardized, and are not unique. Ex: IST = Iceland Standard Time, Ireland Standard Time, India Standard Time, and so on. See Wikipedia for list of standard time zone names in `Continent/Region`format.

Comment: @BasilBourque ok. but in my case, all I know is that I need UTC (so it's independent from region as far as I understand). then I should use "Etc/UTC" over the "UTC"? I'm still not sure why, I like "UTC" form more... however, it says it's deprecated..

Comment: @Line In Java, use the predefined constant, [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

Comment: @BasilBourque ok, but can you explain why?

Comment: Note that using the above method, the returned `Instant` might not represent the intended time which was given as `LocalDateTime`. They are rare cases, but during the transition of Daylight Saving Time, some time periods (a few hours per year) are either non-existent or ambiguous (e.g. 3:30 at night, if the clocks are turned from 03:00->04:00 and an hour is skipped). More information on handling these cases (quite simple actually): https://stackoverflow.com/q/43196341/2237467

Comment: @user924 You could use [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()) if you want the system's time zone.

Answer (score 12):

Forget the old TimeZone class. Use `ZoneId`, because it's properly thread-safe and you can just use a final static field to store the zone.

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 1, 13, 39);
ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, ZoneId.of("ECT")).toInstant();
```

Answer (score -4):

I think the following code should work:

```
LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 15, 13, 39);
ZonedDateTime.of(time, TimeZone.getTimeZone("ZONE").toZoneId()).toInstant();
```

You just have to replace "ZONE" with the timezone you need.

Comment: No, TimeZone is the legacy class, now supplanted by ZoneId and ZoneOffset. Avoid the legacy date-time classes. And certainly do not mix the legacy classes with java.time classes. Please correct or delete your Answer.